# If a neighbourhood of the origin shrinks to the origin then its closure also shrinks to the origin?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

In the proof of the open mapping theorem (theorem 2.11) in his *Functional Analysis*, Rudin states

> ... $y_{m+1} \rightarrow 0$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$ (by the continuity of $\Lambda$)...

In the theorem, $\Lambda : X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous linear mapping from a F-space $X$ to a topological vector space $Y$. And

$$
y_n \in \overline{\Lambda(V_n)}, \; V_n = \{ x \in X : d(x,0) < 2^{-n}r \},
$$ 
where $d$ is a metric of $X$ compatible with its topology and $r > 0$.

I understand that each point in $\Lambda(V_n)$ goes to the origin by the continuity of $\Lambda$. But I cannot prove that its accumulation points also go to the origin.

Comment: What is an F-space?

Comment: The definition in the book is as follows: $X$ is an F-space if its topology $\tau$ is induced by a complete invariant metric $d$.

Comment: i.e., an $F$-space is like a Fréchet space, but doesn't need to be locally convex. (_warning_: other authors use $F$-space as a shorthand for Fréchet space, but this is not Rudin' case.)

Answer (score 1):

The following is the Theorem 1.11 of Rudin's book.

> If $\cal B$ is a local base for a topological vector space $X$, then 
>   every member of $\cal B$ contains the closure of some member of $\cal B$.

Let $V$ be a neighbourhood of $0$ in $X$.
Then, there exists $U_0 \in {\cal B}$ such that $U_0 \subset V$.
It follows from Theorem 1.11 that there exists $U_1 \in {\cal B}$ such that 
$\overline{U_1} \subset U_0$. Since $\Lambda$ is continuous, there exists $N \in {\mathbb N}$ such that
$$
V_n \subset \Lambda^{-1}(U_1), \; n \geq N.
$$
Then,
$$
\Lambda(V_n) \subset U_1, \; n \geq N. \Rightarrow
y_n \in \overline{\Lambda(V_n)} \subset \overline{U_1} \subset U_0 \subset V, \; n \geq N.
$$